# travel cost - most hops with least total cost - modified Dijkstra?

Tags: networking, dijkstra

I have quite a few destinations I would like to visit. They are all a short flight away. The flight prices vary by a few hundred percent. 
So I scrap a price finder for all the routes on all dates between the cities I want to visit.

So for instance:
A->B 08/23/2019: 20€
A->B 09/23/2019: 180€
...
...
C->D 
C->A
and so on.

There are >20 possible nodes/places to visit.

Now I would like to find the route A->B->C->A that has the most flights and the least total cost.

Any pointers on how to do that? Any pre-made adaptable solutions out there?

thank you
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

That problem can be modeled as Dijkstra.

As node content, you take the „visited“ state of each destination and the destination where you are now. Additionally, you have the date, when you got there. In start node, all destinations are not visited, and you are today at home. In target node, all destinations are visited, and you are at home at some later date.

An edge leads from a state with n visited destinations to all states where exactly one of the previous unvisited destinations changes to visited. The weight of an edge is the flight costs from actual to newly visited destinations. If all destinations are visited, the only remaining edge is from actual destination to home. Additionally, each edge has the date when the price is valid. Legal edges are those with a later date.